# Possible to extract compiled flash file?

Tags: flash, resources

I need to get string data from compiled flash .exe file. This file using project.exe to compiled from *.swf

Is it possible to extruct and get string data?

Comment: swf decompiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) is the best out there for this, but it costs a bit:

> SWF Decompiler Features
>
> Decompile SWF to FLA.
>  Decompile
>   SWF to FLEX project, and get MXML file
>   and other project files.
>   **Decompile the standard EXE made by Adobe Flash to FLA format.**
>   Support Flash 6, Flash MX 2004 (V7),
>   Flash 8, Flash CS3 (V9) and Flash CS4
>   (V10).
>  Compatible with
>   ActionScript 2 and ActionScript 3.
>   Export SWF to FLA/SWF to FLEX
>   projects, and extract resources in
>   batch mode.
>  Support exporting the
>   resources to SWF or FLA format.
>   Extract element into various formats,
>   including shapes, sounds, images,
>   sprites, fonts, texts, ActionScript,
>   etc.
>  Export ActionScript file in
>   AS, BIN or HTML format.
>  Export the
>   video file in FLV format from Flash
>   movie.
>  Multi-Language interface is
>   available, English, German and
>   traditional Chinese included.

A free alternative is [Decompile Flash Free Version.](http://www.decompileflash.com/)

Answer (score 4):

- [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) - SWF manipulation and generation utilities

  You can install SWFTools distribution (which has also a command line program), and use [SWFExtract](http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html), that can decompile flash files.

  On OSX, install via: `brew install swftools`.

  This will install tools such as: `as3compile`, `font2swf`, `jpeg2swf`, `pdf2swf`, `png2swf`,
  `swfbbox`, `swfc`, `swfcombine`,
  `swfdump`, `swfextract`, `swfrender`, `swfstrings`, `wav2swf`.

  `swfextracts` allows to extract swf movieclips and objects out of swf files.
- [FFDec](https://www.free-decompiler.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler)) - JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler

  > Opensource flash SWF decompiler and editor. Extract resources, convert SWF to FLA, edit ActionScript, replace images, sounds, texts or fonts. Various output formats available. Works with Java on Windows, Linux or MacOS.

  Examples:

  ```
  java -jar ffdec.jar myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -proxy
  java -jar ffdec.jar -proxy -P1234
  java -jar ffdec.jar -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -selectclass com.example.MyClass,com.example.SecondClass -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format script:pcode -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format script:pcode,text:plain -export script,text,image "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format fla:cs5.5 -export fla "C:\sources\myfile.fla" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -dumpSWF myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -compress myfile.swf myfiledec.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -decompress myfiledec.swf myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -onerror ignore -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -onerror retry 5 -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -config autoDeobfuscate=1,parallelSpeedUp=0 -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  ```

  > Instead of "java -jar ffdec.jar" you can use ffdec.bat on Windows, ffdec.sh on Linux/MacOs

Answer (score 1):

[Decompile Flash Free Version](http://www.decompileflash.com/decompile_flash_free/)

> Decompile Flash Free Version is an outstanding SWF decompiling tool which allows you to convert flash between SWF and FLA format.  Decompile Flash offers the powerful function of editing dynamic texts of flash movie and replacing images as your own easily and watch the edited result immediately. The easy-to-use interface helps you catch on to the system quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the free [Northcode EXE 2 SWF](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/02/Extract-SWF-files-from-Flash-Executables) to extract the SWF out of your Flash projector EXE. Now you can decompile the SWF using a trial version of your favorite decompiler, to access the SWF's contents.